# How to "join" two SQL command outputs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning SQL. My search hasn't been fruitful as I don't think I'm using the right terminology.

I have a table with a datetime column in Postgresql. What I want to do is create a single column in the resultset that outputs like: `Q2/'22` or `Q4/'23`.

I've tried using `+` but that doesn't work (I get an error). I'm not sure how to proceed further. Is there a way in SQL?

```
SELECT 
    name, COUNT(name), 
    DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date) AS quarterview,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date) = '2022-04-01 00:00:00' 
            THEN EXTRACT(quarter FROM DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date)) + '/\'' + EXTRACT(year FROM DATE_TRUNC('year', date))
    END
FROM
    mytable
```

Is there a better way to do this? otherwise I will have to write case for each quarter and for each year.

Also in the case statement I tried to use the alias "quarterview" but got an error to say that "quarterview" is not a column. Is there a way to use the alias instead of writing the `DATE_TRUNC` multiple times?

Comment: I cannot post as an answer, because you are asking the wrong question :) You do not need to truncate, extract and join. You need to format your timestamp column, have a read here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Instead of `DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date) as quarterview` try using `to_char(date, 'Q/YY')`

Comment: Correct question would be "How to format dates as string"

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `TO_CHAR` function combined with string concatenation like below check this

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    count(name),
    'Q' || extract(quarter from date) || '/''' || substring(cast(extract(year from date) as text) from 3 for 2) as quarter_year_format
FROM 
    mytable
GROUP BY 
    name, quarter_year_format;
```